Reduced-Win-Quota STV
Question
In Single Transferable Vote (STV), what would be the effects of setting seatsTotal = candidatesRemaining - 1 (until seatsTotal = seatsDesired) when calculating the votesToWinSeat quota?

The significant processing increase is known.
Would this have an effect similar to an STV-Condorcet hybrid?
How would this affect vote strategizing?

Example
A race for 4 seats with 8 candidates.
Typically, you would run the STV process to determine:

4 seats from  8 candidates.

What if you instead ran the STV process to determine:

7 seats from  8 candidates.
6 seats from the remaining 7 candidates.
5 seats from the remaining 6 candidates.
4 seats from the remaining 5 candidates.

For this example, in typical STV, votesBeforeSharing > votesTotal / 5 across all eliminations. In the What If, votesBeforeSharing starts at > votesTotal / 8 before the first elimination.
Background
Single Transferable Vote (STV) is a multiwinner ranked-choice voting method.
The process can be oversimplified as:

Check for candidates with more votes than needed to win a seat.

 Droop quota: votesToWinSeat > votesTotal / ( seats + 1 )
If so, use a predetermined method to move excess votes to other candidates.


Once any vote rearranging completes, eliminate candidate with lowest votes.

Shift eliminated candidate's votes to vote owners' next best remaining candidate, if any.


If number of candidates remaining = number of seats, end.

Else, repeat.




This question could be improved by clarifying how you think STV works, and how your proposed system differs. Welcome, and enjoy!

One problem would be that under STV voters don't always use all their votes - they might pick a 1 and 2 and leave the rest. Do you want a system where people vote against candidates and the least-hated is picked

@StuartF: Is that an argument regarding this variant of STV or STV in general? In STV, your vote sticks with your highest preference until they are eliminated or your candidate passed the droop quota and thus your vote (or some portion of it) is passed to your next best ranking(s). Here, before the first elimination, the droop quota for 7 winners will be much lower than for 4 winners , thus more excess will shift to other candidates, thus whoever gets eliminated will represent a more rounded reflection of preferences.
